# Unity 2d - I want to remove the rotation of the image in a top down game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to fix the code
So the image doesn't spin when translating to the next point
I tried to fix it, but could not

Apologized to the mistakes of writing, I do not speak English

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V59B2.jpg)

```js
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] patrolPoints;
    Transform currentPatrolPoint;
    int currentPatrolIndex;
    protected override void Start()
    {
        currentPatrolIndex = 0;
        currentPatrolPoint = patrolPoints[currentPatrolIndex];
        base.Start();
    }

    protected override void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * MySpeed);
      
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position,currentPatrolPoint.position)<0.1f)
        {
            if(currentPatrolIndex+1<patrolPoints.Length)
            {
                currentPatrolIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                currentPatrolIndex = 0;
            }
            currentPatrolPoint = patrolPoints[currentPatrolIndex];
        }

        Vector3 patrolPointDirection = currentPatrolPoint.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(patrolPointDirection.y, patrolPointDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, q,180f);
     
  
    }
```

Comment: So you want that the image rotate or it doesn't rotate? In your text you say: So do not image Turn to the next point . But later in your code use the transform.rotation

Comment: I want the picture to go to the next point but do not rotate around itself

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to rotate, remove this part, which is rotating the GameObject:

```
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(patrolPointDirection.y, patrolPointDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, q,180f);
```

Also any variable that you are using just for the transform.rotation can be removed from your code.